# How can I add value to the missing datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add zero to step with missing datetime. I know reindex for simple data, but for this data with datetime, i dont think i can use reindex.

```
    {'dateTime': {0: '11/22/19 00:51:00',
  1: '11/22/19 00:52:00',
  2: '11/22/19 00:53:00',
  3: '11/22/19 00:54:00',
  4: '11/22/19 00:56:00',
  5: '11/22/19 00:57:00',
  6: '11/22/19 01:01:00'},
 'step': {0: 0, 1: 49, 2: 64, 3: 0, 4: 12, 5: 0, 6: 0}}
```

the output i want:

```
    dateTime  step
0   11/22/19 00:51:00     0
1   11/22/19 00:52:00    49
2   11/22/19 00:53:00    64
3   11/22/19 00:54:00     0
4   11/22/19 00:55:00     0
5   11/22/19 00:56:00    12
6   11/22/19 00:57:00     0
7   11/22/19 00:58:00     0
8   11/22/19 00:59:00     0
9   11/22/19 01:00:00     0
10  11/22/19 01:01:00     0
```

Comment: Can you show me the dataframe before add missing value and after add missing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the datetime column to become the index. Once it is, you can resample at 60 sec interval and then reset the index.

```
d = .... # Your dataframe
d = d.set_index('dateTime')
d.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(d.index)  
d.resample('60s').sum().reset_index()
#              dateTime  step
#0  2019-11-22 00:51:00     0
#1  2019-11-22 00:52:00    49
#2  2019-11-22 00:53:00    64
#3  2019-11-22 00:54:00     0
#4  2019-11-22 00:55:00     0
#5  2019-11-22 00:56:00    12
#6  2019-11-22 00:57:00     0
#7  2019-11-22 00:58:00     0
#8  2019-11-22 00:59:00     0
#9  2019-11-22 01:00:00     0
#10 2019-11-22 01:01:00     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are trying to add new datetime indices to your index, and fill the values in `step` with 0...if this is not your aim please correct me..if it is, you can also do it like this, similar to @DYZ's answer:

```
df = df.set_index('dateTime')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
new_index = pd.date_range(start = df.index[0], end = df.index[-1], freq = '60s')
df = df.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = ['dateTime','step']
```

there's probably a way some of this can be simplified a bit

output:

```
              dateTime  step
0  2019-11-22 00:51:00     0
1  2019-11-22 00:52:00    49
2  2019-11-22 00:53:00    64
3  2019-11-22 00:54:00     0
4  2019-11-22 00:55:00     0
5  2019-11-22 00:56:00    12
6  2019-11-22 00:57:00     0
7  2019-11-22 00:58:00     0
8  2019-11-22 00:59:00     0
9  2019-11-22 01:00:00     0
10 2019-11-22 01:01:00     0
```